# Is it possible to have a background process detect screen capture

Tags: android

I want to build n app that detects when the user takes a screenshot then get the image and use it.

Is it possible without root? My idea is very crude. the app will scan the screenshots holder for changes every second but that is very inefficient. is there another way?

Comment: No there is no another way as of yet

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is no supported way of doing that. You could try the `FileObserver` class though and watch for events. Look here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html